# PHP Sorting Files RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, sorting, recursion, spl

I'm listing the files in my subdirectory just fine using the following code

```
// Create recursive dir iterator and skip the dot folders
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.',
FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

// Folders come before their files
$file  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

// Maximum depth is 2
$file->setMaxDepth(2);

// Pull out all the xml files that don't contain numbers or special characters
foreach ($file as $fileinfo) {
if ($file->isFile()&& preg_match("/^[a-z]+\.xml/i",$file->getFilename())) {
 $linkname = simplexml_load_file($file->getSubPath().'/'.$file->getFilename());
 echo '<li><a href="'. $file->getSubPath().'/'.$file->getFilename().'">'. $linkname->name .'</a> -' . date('Y-m-d',filemtime($file->getPathName())) . '</li>';
 }
}
```

What I would really like it to do is list them by date modified newest first and be able to limit the number of files returned to a configurable value.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// Create recursive dir iterator and skip the dot folders
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

// Folders come before their files
$file = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

// Maximum depth is 2
$file->setMaxDepth(2);

foreach(new LimitIterator(new SortedFileIterator($file, "xml"), 0, 10) as $fileinfo) {
    printf("%s = %s \n", $fileinfo, date("Y-m-d g:i:s", $fileinfo->getMTime()));
    // Do your stuff
}
```

A simple way is using `SplHeap`

```
class SortedFileIterator extends SplHeap {
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $ext) {
        foreach($iterator as $item) {
            if ($item->isFile() && $item->getExtension() == $ext) {
                $this->insert($item);
            }
        }
    }
    public function compare($b, $a) {
        return $a->getMTime() == $b->getMTime() ? 0 : ($a->getMTime() > $b->getMTime() ? 1 : - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: $filter = new RecursiveRegexIterator($dir, '/[a-z]+\.xml$/i'); prevents it from listing subdirectories though.

Comment: Ok I sorted out the recursion problem and the output is now ordering by date last modified. Now for the second part, was there a way to use this to limit the results to X? Like just the first 10?

Comment: Right but, foreach(new LimitIterator(new SortedIterator($file), $limit) as $fileinfo) { no longer orders the listing by newest first.

Answer (score 1):

The solution SortedFileIterator is very interesting.
The insert of SplHeap don't preserve the pathname as key of the SplFileInfo.

```
$iteFile = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($iteFile as $pathname => $cur){
    echo $pathname;
}
```

with SortedFileIterator

```
$iteFile = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$ite = new SortedFileIterator($itefile,$ext);
foreach($ite as $cur){
    $pathname=$cur->getPathname();
}
```